# Trying to add a link to an image

Tags: image, gridview, hyperlink

I need some help. Here's what I have done so far. I want to have a gridview layout and add images to them that link to different url

```
body: Center(
      child: Material(
        elevation: 10,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.grey,
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 3),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            ),
            child: Ink.image(
              image: const AssetImage('images/APPvideogames2.jpg'),
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap it with `GestureDetector` then onTap you are able to redirect it to the link you provide

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).